# Finding the average of multiple ranges

Tags: statistics, average

I conducted a survey where participants inputted a range for their weekly tablet usage. For example, someone was able to say they used their tablet "11 - 15 hrs/week". How do I find the average hr/week usage when I have a range?

Thanks for the help! Elementary school math is failing me right now :/

Comment: It seems not unreasonable to first find the average midpoint $\bar m$ for all intervals, then find the average width $\bar w$ of all intervals. Then you could use $[\bar m - \bar w/2, \bar m + \bar w/2]$ as an average interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if each participants input a range, I guess the answer should also offer a range so you do the average of each min and each max and say the average is between avg(min) and avg(max).

Else if only some people answered a range, than I would select the median value. The best would be to calculate the average of that range but since we only have one occurence, we can't.